# Having the starred version of a theorem environment unnumbered - with ntheorem

Tags: numbering, amsmath, theorems, starred-version, ntheorem

I'm trying to switch from `amsthm` to `ntheorem`. (This is due to the incompatibility of `amsthm` with babel+Hebrew, see [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.miktex/5791) and [here](http://www.whatsup.org.il/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=45168); seems not to have been resolved.)

I would like to have both a starred and unstarred versions of certain environments, with the starred version being unnumbered. With `amsthm` I would do:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
```

and this does what I want. With `ntheorem`, this results in an error - `theorem*` is already defined; removing the second command, both environments come out numbered, and the difference is that the `theorem*` doesn't get included in the list of theorems (which I don't use anyway). I tried this both with the `[amsthm]` option of `ntheorem` and without it.

Is there anything I can do other then give up `theorem*` in favor of something like

```
\newtheorem*{theoremstar}{Theorem}
```

?

Comment: If the switch is **away** from `amsthm` rather than **to** `ntheorem`, you could define your own (starred and unstarred) versions of `theorem` using primitives, rather defining them via `ntheorem`. Would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the `ntheorem` documentation, I saw `\renewtheorem` mentioned; so:

```
\renewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
```

is a working hack. Now, if only I could macroize the choice between `newtheorem` and `renewtheorem`, so that I can use the same preamble code for both `ntheorem` and `amsthm`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any other possibility than the one you mention too, i.e., `\newtheorem*{theoremstar}{Theorem}`. It looks a bit unwieldy, but it works!

**Addendum** 2 Oct 2011: Please see my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30262/ntheorem-with-the-amsthm-option-ignores-styling-of-a-theorem-environment) for a more complete answer to your question about how to create a theorem style in which the "starred" version of a theorem is unnumbered.

Comment: It is because `ntheorem` has a feature where it can make a list of theorems. And `theorem*` will then `not` add an entry to this list. IMO when users are not using this feature, they should be allowed to use `theorem*` in the manner the OP wants. One may send this as a suggestion to Wolfgang May (the `ntheorem` author).

Comment: I just wrote him. One of the ways this could be done is making the list-of-theorems capability a package option, and if you choose not to have it, the theorem* environments don't get defined. Of course, all this wouldn't really help me since I can't have my thesis rely on yet-unreleased package versions... I'll have to make do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Re OP's answer: what about

```
\providecommand{\renewtheorem}{\newtheorem}
```

so that `\renewtheorem` is defined as `\newtheorem` when using `amsthm` and is not redefined when using `ntheorem`?  This is a dirty hack, but should work irrespective of which of `amsthm` or `ntheorem` is used.

A cleaner version would be

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{what if loaded}{what if not}
\@ifpackageloaded{ntheorem}{what if loaded}{what if not}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Well, giving \renewtheorem the semantics of \newtheorem is a bit confusing, I feel. As for `\@ifpackageloaded`, that's something, but in itself it means some redundancy, or interspersing `\@ifpackageloaded`s with common code. I guess there's not much that can be done beyond that though.

Comment: Well, what you also could do is to write one's own "theorem" package.  I do not know much about `ntheorem`, but `amsthm` is somewhat broken anyway, so this might actually be a good idea.

Comment: If I had spare time on my hands, I might... something like the `algpseudocode` which make `algorithmicx` behave like algorithm, right?