# ntheorem with the [amsthm] option ignores styling of a theorem environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ntheorem

I'm using `ntheorem` with the `amsthm` option, to define a theorem-like environment for stating notes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem*{myenv}{Note}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

I should be getting an environment beginning with the word 'Note' in italic font, followed by the contents in normal roman font. Instead, I get 'Note' in boldface roman and the body in italic:

[image]

Trying to define a new theoremstyle doesn't seem to work either:

```
\newtheoremstyle{nonumberabc}%
  {\item[\normalfont\itshape \hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]\normalfont}%
  {\item[{\normalfont\itshape \hskip \labelsep ##3}\theorem@separator]\normalfont}
\theoremstyle{abc}
\newtheorem*{myenv}{Note}
```

this gives the same results with the above document.

What am I doing wrong?

The problem does not occur if I drop the `amsthm` option - but then I don't get some nice amsthm definitions I'm expecting... (it was psychologically hard enough to drop amsthm for ntheorem after years or use!) Most importantly, I like the `amsthm` proof environment. So, for those suggesting that I just drop `amsthm` - how can I reproduce proof with the exact same behavior (including the QED box size etc.) with `ntheorem`? I can't just lift code out of `ntheorem`, because it doesn't seem to use its own theoremstyle commands to get the proof environment. Rather, it does something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30267/5640) and my comment there, here's code for a proof environment with the final-period-mark issue fixed; it's a slight tweak of the code Werner lifted from the `ntheorem' sources:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\gdef\proofSymbol{\openbox}
\newcommand{\proofname}{Proof}
\newcounter{proof}\newcounter{currproofctr}\newcounter{endproofctr}%
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{
  \th@nonumberplain
  \def\theorem@headerfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont
  %\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
  \@thm{proof}{proof}{{#1}.}}%
  {\@endtheorem}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 5):

> I'm using ntheorem with the amsthm option. I should be getting a
>   environment with 'Note' in italic and the contents in normal roman
>   font. Instead, I get 'Note' in boldface roman and the body in italic.
>   What am I doing wrong?

I believe you need to provide a couple of `\newtheoremstyle` commands before you can issue the command `\newtheorem{myenv}{Note}`. According to the documentation of the `ntheorem` package, the theoremstyles of both numbered and unnumbered "theorem" environments must be defined explicitly if the package was loaded with the `amsthm` option. Here's what I suggest you do in the preamble, given your description of how you'd like the "note" environment to be styled:

```
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheoremstyle{notes} % for numbered notes
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \itshape ##1\ ##2.]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \itshape ##1\ ##2, ##3.]}
\newtheoremstyle{nonumbernotes} % for unnumbered notes
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \itshape ##1.]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \itshape ##1, ##3.]}
\theoremstyle{notes} % switch to newly defined theorem style
\newtheorem*{myenv}{Note}
```

After this, you should have no problems with your `myenv` environments.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to "lift" the `proof` environment code from [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\gdef\proofSymbol{\openbox}
\newcommand{\proofname}{Proof.}
\newcounter{proof}\newcounter{currproofctr}\newcounter{endproofctr}%
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{
  \th@nonumberplain
  \def\theorem@headerfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont
  %\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
  \@thm{proof}{proof}{#1}}%
  {\@endtheorem}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem*{myenv}{Note}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\begin{proof}
This statement is true, because the fox did jump over the lazy dog.
\end{proof}
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

[image: ntheorem with amsthm proof environment]

The QED-symbol is displayed when using the `thmmarks` package option of `ntheorem`. In `ntheorem` this is manually defined in `\openbox`, and subsequently used as `\proofSymbol`.

Comment: It's missing the point after 'Proof'. I can add that, I hope it's not missing anything else.

Comment: As mentioned, the above was "lifted" from `ntheorem` based on the `amsthm` style option. Based on a browse of `amsmath.sty`, the only addition is `\ignorespace` after typesetting the point/period after *Proof*.

Comment: Added a slightly modified version as an alternative answer, you're welcome to have a look.

Comment: `\blacksquare` seems to [require other packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30762/5640).

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes, `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @einpoklum: I don't use `\blacksquare` in my answer, so there's no need for `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Answer (score 4):

The [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf) answered as follows:

**3.2.2 amsthm**

> Here, the user has to express his definitions by the `\newtheoremstyle`
>   command provided by `ntheorem.sty`, including the use of
>   `\theoremheaderfont` and `\theorembodyfont`. The options `[amsthm]` and
>   `[standard]` are in conflict since they both define an environment
>   `proof`. *Thus, we recommend not to use `amsthm`*, since the features for
>   defining theorem-like environments in `ntheorem.sty`—following
>   `theorem.sty`—seem to be more intuitive and user-friendly.

[Package ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem)

To get a similar proof environment without the option `amsthm` you get do the following:

```
 \documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}

\theoremsymbol{\openbox}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem*{myenv}{Note}



\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{myenv}

\begin{proof}[Alternative Text]
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I'm not using the [standard] option... and I do like amsthm's proof.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: Please see my edit.

Comment: Your suggestion has a significant issue with optional arguments: Try `\begin{proof}[Alternative Text]` ... you get the Atlernative text twice.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: I fixed it.