# Any reason why \blacksquare and \box are causing errors?

Tags: symbols, errors, amsmath

I am using the `amsmath` package. I just want a black box at the end of a proof, right-justified.

`\blacksquare` and `\box` both cause errors.

Actually, I'd prefer a musical quarter note if that's possible :)

Comment: The `wasysym` package provides `\quarternote`.

Comment: what, precisely, are the errors?  the open square used by `amsthm` (not defined in `amsmath`) is the open box at location hex03 in the `msam` font if `amsfonts` are loaded, otherwise it's a drawn box. if you're using `amsthm`, you can simply `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{...}` with whatever symbol you want, but if you're not using `amsthm`, i can't help without knowing more.

Comment: The `\blacksquare` is defined in `amssymb`.

Answer (score 21):

Are you including the appropriate packages?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{MnSymbol}%
\usepackage{wasysym}%

\begin{document}
$\blacksquare$  \halfnote \quarternote
\end{document}
```

See [LaTeX Comprehensive symbols list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: I was only including amsmath

Comment: The \blacksquare is defined in amssymb.

Comment: @mtc: Good point. So instead of `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` one can use `\usepackage{amssymb}`.