# Error report in texniccenter

Tags: blackboard

I had written this in texniccenter, and when I did ctrl+F7 it gave me error as "undefined control sequence". I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Is there something wrong in my code? I also downloaded the package "bbm" and added it in the beginning but nothing is working. Can someone help me? Hope this is not too silly for this forum.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\section{Problems}
\label{sec:Problems}
\begin{flushleft}
This approach helps a lot since equality cases can be easily obtained.
The left side's >equality case is $r = 1$.
The right side's equality case occur when $y = rx$ passes
through the interior of exactly $n$ squares.
Such cases occur when $r$ is either an
integer, reciprocal of an integer, $r \geq n$ or $0 < r \leq 1/n$.
  $\blacksquare$
\end{flushleft}

2.Determine all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\[f(xy+f(x))=f(x)f(y)+x , \ \ \ \forall x,y \in  \mathbb{R}.\] 
\end{document}
```

This is what I wrote down. My alignment is pretty ugly here, and I apologise for that, but ugliness is better than incorrect code. Also, this is my first time using an editor. Usually I write on \LaTeX\ enabled platforms, such as math SE, MO etc. Also the part from "This approach..." is the ending of another problem, I omitted everything but kept this part so it might be clear about the errors. Also, I want to give a black square when the solution ends, I tried to give it, and that also gives "Undefined control sequence:. Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\mathbb` is defined in  `amsfonts` package

Comment: Note that the editor used to create the file (texniccenter here) is not really relevant to the error message which comes from the underlying TeX system, I retagged the question removing the texniccenter tag

Comment: I am writing a document and it came in between, should I post the whole code? I thought it would be too long.

Comment: No, you should reduce your code to the minimum that still demonstrates the issue, and post that. But to repeat what others have said: have you got `\usepackage{amsfonts}` or `\usepackage{amssymb}`?

Comment: No, I have `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{bbm}` only. See the edit there. :)

Comment: Well, you need one of those. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38769)

Comment: note you can mark code sections with `{}` button (which indents by 4 spaces)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the package `bbm`, the correct command would be `\mathbbm{R}` here. But as you will need [some more package for your `\blacksquare`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30762) I would recommend the package `amssymb` which is often used and contains the package `amsfonts`. The latter contains the command ([`\mathbb{R}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38769)) you are using at the moment.

I would recommend to use the following MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} % not needed here, but it loads most of the stuff you will need. E.g. `amsmath`

\begin{document}
\section{Problems}
\label{sec:Problems}
\begin{flushleft}
This approach helps a lot since equality cases can be easily obtained.
The left side's equality case is $r = 1$.
The right side's equality case occurs when $y = rx$ passes
through the interior of exactly $n$ squares.
Such cases occur when $r$ is either an
integer, reciprocal of an integer, $r \geq n$ or $0 < r \leq 1/n$.
 $\blacksquare$
\end{flushleft}

2. Determine all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\[f(xy+f(x))=f(x)f(y)+x , \quad \forall x,y \in  \mathbb{R}.\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I do this, I still get errors, three errors are given {LaTeX error : File `mathtools.sty` not found.}, {Emergency stop}, {==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!}, what should I do now? Please help me.

Comment: @shadow10 Are you using MiKTeX or TexLive? You should update your TeX distribution and search this site for "how to install packages". For my example you can leave `mathtools` away or you just load `amsmath` instead.

Comment: I am using MikTeX. So mathtools package is not there in MikTeX? OK thanks a lot for that.

Comment: @shadow10 Open MiKTeX--Maintenance--Package Manager and search for mathtools. Then install it.

Comment: OK, I seem to have another problem. See, I did install MikTeX but the shortcut is named "TeXmaker" there is another one I had installed, which is named "TeXworks", and I couldn't find the maintenance option anywhere. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @shadow10 Well, TeXmaker and TeXworks are both editors and thus not the right thing you are searching. There should be a folder MiKTeX in your start menu. You can search the MiKTeX installation itself on your hard drive. For me, the package manager can be found under `D:\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\mpm.exe`